# Successor of ContextDecorator doesn't work: 'generator' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with inheriting from the `ContextDecorator` class. I can't understand why the method `session_manager()` works:

```
@contextmanager
def session_manager():
    session = Session()
    yield session
    try:
    session.commit()
except Exception as e:
    session.rollback()
    raise e
finally:
    session.close()
```

But exactly the same code with `ContextDecorator` successor class gives an error:

```
class SessionManager(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            yield self.session
            self.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise e

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.session.close()
```

---

Exception:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'add'
```

The documentation and tutorials do not have complex examples (only with 'print' statements) and they works great: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

I don't understand why method `session_manager()` works, although it returns a generator:

```
yield session
```

Here I write some small and simple code:
https://gist.github.com/tranebaer/46f94263030dd8f7c1bfcf72d0e37610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) method is not supposed to be a generator, unless you want to treat the return value as such in the runtime context. It is called when entering the block governed by the with-statement and its return value is bound to the target(s) specified in the [`as`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#as) clause, if any. So the attribute error is the result of calling the method `add()` on the generator inside the block, when you meant it to be the `Session` object. Possible cleanup and exception handling should take place in the [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) method:

```
from contextlib import closing, ContextDecorator, ExitStack

class SessionManager(ContextDecorator):

    def __init__(self, session_cls=Session):
        self.session = session_cls()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.session

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        with closing(self.session), ExitStack() as stack:
            stack.callback(self.session.rollback)
            if not value:
                self.session.commit()
                # If commit raises an exception, then rollback is left
                # in the exit stack.
                stack.pop_all()
```

Note that you don't need to inherit from [`ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) in order to make a context manager. Just implementing `__enter__` and `__exit__` is enough. In fact in this case it is a bit pointless, because a function decorated with `SessionManager` [has no access to the `Session` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#using-a-context-manager-as-a-function-decorator).